# How to set some parameter in end state externalredirect in Spring Webflow?

Tags: spring, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

My question is regarding Spring Webflow. How can we set a variable in the end state?

```
<action-state id="saveanyformula">
    <evaluate expression="--code---"></evaluate>
    <transition to="end"></transition>
</action-state>

<end-state id="end" view="externalRedirect:new/lists">
```

I have try below code but it is not working:

```
<end-state id="end" view="externalRedirect:new/lists?foo1=${flowScope.foo1}">
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This :

```
 <end-state id="end" view="externalRedirect:new/lists?foo1=#{flowScope.foo1}">
```